# Retrofit 2 , в каких случаях стоит отказаться от библиотеки. Как было раньше, как стало с Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

Я тяжело понимаю плюсы этой библиотеки. 
 Например: **Очень простой и гибкий способ описать API в коде**  Так ведь раньше, тоже всё так и делалось: получил json, кинул на сайт http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ и получил свой класс , другой плюс **Сам парсит**, не фига не сам, а использует ту же `Gson` библиотеку или другую, в зависимости от того, что надо парсить.  Всё что сделано в библиотеке, объединены другие библиотеки. Далее **Асинхронные запросы**, ну есть обертка над интерфейсом `Runnable`, но от написания `AsyncTask` в случае не долгих запросов не освобождает.  **Синхронный запрос**, приходится использовать `AsyncTask` , т.к. запрос автоматически в доп. потоке не запускается.

Ну вот допустим мне надо выполнять один запрос и получать данные, которые грузятся за миллисекунды. Нужен ли мне `retrofit`? Как я понимаю библиотека оправдывает себя только при работе с сложным rest api ?
Понимаю, что лучше всего взять сетевой интерфейс сайта и сперва написать всё без использования библиотеки, а потом попробовать библиотеку, но это долго)

Comment: я думал rx все решает. Я на самом деле программированием не так давно занимаюсь,мнепоказался удобным решением для работы в связке (rx, gson, retrofit +- dagger). Для меня ретрофит представляется простым и удобным инструментом для создания rest запросов, а сам он является обёрткой над HTTPUrlConnection (так ведь, поправьте, если я не прав. Спасибо).  "Всё что сделано в библиотеке, объединены другие библиотеки." - а что в этом плохо? А разве spring не подобное решение? Зачем он, берите сами все пишите и реализуйте. Разве нет? Готовое, быстрое решение и проверенное.

Comment: не над HTTPUrlConnection , там вроде okHttp.

Comment: Если вы не видите и не чувствуете преимуществ при использовании либы, и аналогичную задачу вы решаете, по вашему мнению быстрей и проще, тогда вам стоит отказаться. Ибо нет ничего хуже чем использовать то в чем не разбираетесь , этот проблема даже опытных разработчиков, которые имеют уже сильную базу и используют новые паттерны для себя не по назначению или пытаются решить задачу не по назначению , такой код очень тяжело поддается рефатклрингу, это хуже чем просто места с ошибками у начинающих разрабов, хотя они тоже могут.

Comment: Аналогия если вы пишите HelloWorld и тяните за собой чтот типо Di+Rx+MVP вы просто ваш хеловорд превратите в монстра. Поэтому решать задачи и использовать либы необходимо только если они удобны для команды иначе будете коленки отбивать

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei аналогия правильная конечно, но как вы узнаете,  что ваш helloworld не вырастит? Я конечно понимаю, когда вы проект для себя пишите. Тут наверно удобно, я знаю что хочу. (и то откуда я знаю, что у меня будет только hello world) Что вас не будет работать через неделю два десятка человек? Правда, просто интересно, как правильно оценить, необходимость использования стека. Допустим мы не берем di,rx,mvp. Что остается new,MVC,asynktask? Надеюсь на экспертное мнение. Как по мне этот стек один раз настроил, потратил время и затем спокойно используй. Почему нет?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov после заказа, обязательно необходимо проводить проектирование, это очень большой и важный этап и делается он даже если вы 1. На этоп этапе вы можете определить множество необходимых факторов, если коротко то это объем работ для себя и цену для заказчика. Так вот когда будете учитывать объем работ, вы можете определить размер проекта и разбить при необходимости на модули. Зная размер проекта и модули необходимо спроектировать архитектуру вот тогда и выбираете с командой (или 1) что для вас больше подходит. Аналогично моим комментариям.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Все логично. А если первичное проектирование мы проверили и выбрали архитектуру, которая отлично подходит под наше решение и после завершения проекта, заказчику так понравилось что он попросил вас вести функционал, который в ущерб вашей архитектуре пойдет? Может быть такое? Также вопрос, если мы изначально закладываемся на более дорогую архитектуру проекта, по времени для нас и заказчика, стоит ли рассматривать то, что в будущем это сэкономит деньги заказчика, а вам упростит работу с таким кодом?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Вот у меня мало работы с MVC (а как я понимаю, это классика, для андройда и отлично подходит для небольших проектов), я начал работу на андройде c MVP. Мне в силу моего небольшого опыта MVP показался прожорливым в первичной настройке на проекте (большой холодильник с множеством камер, где в каждой хранится то что нужно), но после очень удобным и каждый слой брал на себя ответственность за одну вещь. MVC мне показалась холодильником (однокамерным) есть все, но ты начинаешь искать где колбаса где молоко и т.д. И вот здесь я понимаю, да я потрачу время на фасовку, но затем всеудобно

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei если все это как то подвести к черте. Стоит ли использовать стек из готовы технологий на старте проекта и затем, при необходимости постепенно заменять на свои?

Comment: стоит, я юзаю изначально templates Android, написал один раз потратил 2-3 дня с изучением сего и каждый раз когда нужно сделать тестовое задаине, накидать пример, и начать проект я кайфую. 

Но... есть например старые проекты, я не готов их переписывать. "работает - не трожь!" аналоигчно с заказами, придет заказ что-то исправить 2-3 места, вы же не будете весь проект перефигаривать, вы лоакльно их исправите и получите деньги. Суть такая.

Comment: Ну да, сперва быстренько написал используя библиотеки, а потом если где нибудь производительности не хватает, допиливаем из того что есть в jdk, но могут возникнут трудности при вырывании кода написанного например на retrofit 2, который уже с rxJava связан..

Comment: Вообще я вопрос ставил не таким образом, я хотел простыми словами услышать про плюсы этой библиотеки. Т.к. я не писал еще практически ничего серьезного связанного с сетевыми технологиями